# How to debug locally Azure Function triggered by EventGrid?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, visual-studio-2022

I create a new Azure Function which I want it to run by EventGrid. I use Visual Studio 2022 Community.

I want to debug the Function by Postman but I couldn't find the way to do it.

My TestFunction.cs:

```
public static class TestFunction
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task Function1([EventGridTrigger] EventGridEvent triggerEvent,
                                              [EventGrid(TopicEndpointUri = "Topic", TopicKeySetting = "TopicKey")] IAsyncCollector<EventGridEvent> outputEvents,
                                              ILogger log)
    {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

When I F5 the project to debug, the console app shows:

```
Functions:

    Function1: eventGridTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
```

I try to post by Postman to the Url:

```
http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/EventGrid?functionName=Function1
```

There are two things that happen:

1.The Postman request returns:

```
cannot find function: 'Function1'
```

2.The console application shows:

```
[2022-03-14T12:20:57.715Z] Executing HTTP request: {
[2022-03-14T12:20:57.717Z]   requestId: "a31453db-3717-43d8-a008-bd459a454fb0",
[2022-03-14T12:20:57.718Z]   method: "POST",
[2022-03-14T12:20:57.718Z]   userAgent: "PostmanRuntime/7.29.0",
[2022-03-14T12:20:57.719Z]   uri: "/runtime/webhooks/EventGrid"
[2022-03-14T12:20:57.721Z] }
[2022-03-14T12:20:57.724Z] cannot find function: 'Function1', available function names: []
[2022-03-14T12:20:57.725Z] Executed HTTP request: {
[2022-03-14T12:20:57.726Z]   requestId: "a31453db-3717-43d8-a008-bd459a454fb0",
[2022-03-14T12:20:57.727Z]   identities: "(WebJobsAuthLevel:Admin, WebJobsAuthLevel:Admin)",
[2022-03-14T12:20:57.728Z]   status: "404",
[2022-03-14T12:20:57.729Z]   duration: "10"
[2022-03-14T12:20:57.729Z] }
```

This is the post which I read to get the Url for debugging: https://harrybellamy.com/posts/debugging-azure-function-event-grid-triggers-locally/

Is there anything which I'm missing in order to debug the Function by Postman?

Thank you in advanced!

---

Update 15.03.2022

When I remove this line (the parameter in Function1) then it works, I can debug the Function1:

```
[EventGrid(TopicEndpointUri = "MyEventGridTopicUriSetting", TopicKeySetting = "MyEventGridTopicKeySetting")]IAsyncCollector<EventGridEvent> outputEvents,
```

Answer (score 3):

The referenced article says:

> If you try to send the request to the URL now, you will find that it doesn’t work. This is because Event Grid requests require a ‘magic’ header for them to work.
>
> Add the following header to your request in your request generator:
>
> `aeg-event-type: Notification`

Comment: I did but it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have an update for 15.03.2022 and it works. But it's still unclear to me why it says "cannot find function" when adding that line.

Comment: This also worked for me in .NET 8.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the official Microsoft documentation on how to [Manually run a non HTTP-triggered function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-manually-run-non-http).

> To run a non HTTP-triggered function, you need a way to send a request to Azure to run the function. The URL used to make this request takes a specific form.
>
> [image: Define the request location: host name + folder path + function name]
>
> - **Host name**: The function app's public location that is made up from the function app's name plus *azurewebsites.net* or your custom domain.
> - **Folder path**: To access non HTTP-triggered functions via an HTTP request, you have to send the request through the folders *admin/functions*.
> - **Function name**: The name of the function you want to run.

This works both in Azure and local.

Next to this, see [Azure Function Event Grid Trigger Local Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-debug-event-grid-trigger-local) which takes an alternative approach of running your Function locally and using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to have Event Grid actually call into your locally running Function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have an update for 15.03.2022 and it works. But it's still unclear to me why it says "cannot find function" when adding that line.

Comment: Is it possible to use dev tunnel to debug event grid trigger function locally ?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/dev-tunnels/get-started?tabs=windows